# Fallback problem when using bidirectional animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I have a layer where I use bidirectional animation (Layer name is "Base Layer")

[screenshot of the layer](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630380035039035404/869743697674240000/Anm.PNG)

For 2 to work, 1 must have finished running. How should I add to the source code below?

(1-direction is triggered by a variable that gets true when I right-click with the mouse)

```
//the function is called inside the update method
private void PunchAnim()
        {
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {
                if (_input.punch)
                {
                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDPunch, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

i tried this but it doesn't work

```
private void PunchAnim()
        {
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {
                if (_input.punch)
                {
                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDPunch, true);
                    int baseLayerIndex =_animator.GetLayerIndex("Base Layer");
                    if (_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(baseLayerIndex).IsName("Punch") && _animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(baseLayerIndex).normalizedTime < 1.0f)
                    {
                     //still working
                    }
                       
                    else
                    {
                       _animator.SetBool(_animIDPunch, false);
                    }
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with below code

```
private void PunchAnim()
        {
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {
                if (_input.punch)
                {
                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDPunch, true);
                }

                int baseLayerIndex = _animator.GetLayerIndex("Base Layer");
                if (_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(baseLayerIndex).IsName("Punch") && (_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(baseLayerIndex).normalizedTime > _animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(baseLayerIndex).length))
                {
                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDPunch, false);
                    _input.punch = false;
                }
            }
        }
```